# Creating a subclass for a UIView for reusability

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subclass, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a DiscoverViewController.h and .m files that have a function that displaces views of places to discover. I want to reuse this view in output viewcontrollers too.  The code for the DicoverViewController.m with the [uiview](/questions/tagged/uiview) is below:

```
for (PFObject *views in objects)
{
  // Get the discoverr view setup
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5.0, _viewStart, 310.0, viewHeight);

  DiscoverView *parent = [[DiscoverView alloc] init];

  [parent buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
  // UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, _viewStart, 310.0, viewHeight)];
  parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  // parent.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
  parent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor regularColor].CGColor;
  parent.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
  parent.tag = 1000 + _step;

  // Add the label counter
  // Add discover id for testing (is unique id)
  UILabel *placeholder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 310.0, 12.0)];
  placeholder.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  placeholder.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  placeholder.textColor = [UIColor bestTextColor];
  placeholder.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:(12.0)];
  placeholder.Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", views.objectId];

  [parent addSubview:placeholder];

  // Increase size of content view
  CGRect newContentView = _contentView.frame;

  newContentView.size.width = _contentView.frame.size.width;
  newContentView.size.height = _contentView.frame.size.height + bestHeight;

  [_contentView setFrame:newContentView];

  [_contentView addSubview:parent];

  scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size;

  // Adjust the postions
  _viewStart = _viewStart + viewHeight - 1.0;
  _step = _step + 1;
}
```

The [uiview](/questions/tagged/uiview) class called DiscoverView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface DiscoverView : UIView

- (UIView *) buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andObjects:(PFObject *) objects;

@end
```

The implementation file DiscoverView.m:

```
- (UIView *) buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andObjects:(PFObject *) objects
{
    UIView *discover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    _photoObject = objects.objectId;

    //Add a gesture to dismiss keyboard on tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(discoverTapPressed)];

    [discover addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return discover;
}

- (void) discoverTapPressed
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The id is:"
                                                message:_photoObject
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Somehow this is not working correctly. The frame won't show in the right space and the tap doesn't work at all. Do I need to change it to be a class reference vs an instance?  How do I reuse this class (DiscoverView) and get this working properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you are not using UITableView or UICollectionView? any specific reason behind creating manual infinite scrollview?

Comment: See my comment below about this (pretty much the table view did 90 percent of the work but the last 10 percent of UI I wanted for my app was tough). But I do use table views and collection views elsewhere where the whole page itself is a collection or table view.

Comment: can you post screenshot of UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is very good and I think you are on the right way ... you just had made some mistakes:

```
- (UIView *)buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andObjects:(PFObject *) objects
{
    //Your method name is buildDiscoverView, but you are making a view
    //that is not a DiscoverView class. 
    UIView *discover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    //Tap gesture stuff...

    return discover;
}
```

And:

```
DiscoverView *parent = [[DiscoverView alloc] init];

//parent will not contain an attached tap gesture, but the view 
//returned from its method does...
[parent buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];

//Ex:
//UIView *viewWithYourTapGesture = [parent buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
```

I 'm pretty sure that it's not what you really want. I think you are trying to build a DiscoveryView instance instead right? you can do it this way:

**On your DiscoveryView.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andObjects:(PFObject *)objects {

    //You can call initWithFrame: method here as our base constructor
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        //Add tap gesture here
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(discoverTapPressed)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        //and maybe do some other stuff as changing the background color
        //or making the border stuff that you are doing outside...
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now you can init your instance as below:

**On your DiscoverViewController.m**

```
DiscoverView *parent = [[DiscoverView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];

//If you do this on init, you don't need this anymore...
//parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//parent.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
//parent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor regularColor].CGColor;
//parent.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

FYI: I also recommend you to check the new `IBDesignable` feature, that allow us to visualize the results directly from Storyboard (but it's NOT what you are asking for on this thread.)

**Update:**

As @abhishekkharwar said, there are many other ways to do this better, as using `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`, but you have to decide what fits better on your app needs. Just try NOT to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Yes I have collection views and tableviews in the app. It was just for these ceratin pages/controllers, that there are more different UI type of things on the page that made a those views not "quite a good fit".  But I do use them in other places (the tableview got me 90 percent there, but the last 10 percent proved difficult to implement using a tableview). I agree NOT reinventing the will is a great thing.

Comment: @chris > Ok, so just change the code the way I wrote above and be happy... I'm sure it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the UIView class called DiscoverView.h to

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andObjects:(PFObject *)objects;
```

change the implementation file DiscoverView.m to :

```
@interface DiscoverView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) id photoObject;
@end
@implementation DiscoverView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andObjects:(PFObject *)objects {

    //You can call initWithFrame: method here as our base constructor
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(discoverTapPressed)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        _photoObject = objects.objectId;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) discoverTapPressed
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"The id is:"
                                                    message:_photoObject
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Replace the code in your old code:

```
   DiscoverView *parent = [[DiscoverView alloc] init];
  [parent buildDiscoverViewWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
  // UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, _viewStart, 310.0, viewHeight)];
  parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  // parent.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
  parent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor regularColor].CGColor;
  parent.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
  parent.tag = 1000 + _step;
```

to

```
    DiscoverView *parent = [[DiscoverView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
    parent.tag = 1000 + _step;
```